# javascript error because of global scope variables

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 3;
(function (){
  console.log('before', x);
  var x = 7;
  console.log('after', x);
  return ;
})();
```

In the above code var X is initialized globally. So inside the function the first console.log should print "before 3" but i don't get it. The reason is that i am trying to re-declare the global variable.

Can somebody explain why this is happening?

Comment: Link answering your question: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting FWIW, you're looking at "hoisting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript parser does [Variable Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) when parsing your code. This means that any variable declaration will be moved to the top of the current scope, thus in your case, this code will get executed:

```
var x = 3;
(function (){
  var x;
  console.log('before', x);
  x = 7;
  console.log('after', x);
  return ;
})();
```

So your local variable `x` gets declared at first with an initial value of `undefined`.

This should explain, why you get an "beforeundefined" for the first `console.log()`.

Answer (score 5):

> In the above code var X is initialized globally. so inside the function the first console.log should print "before 3".

No, it should print `before undefined`, because `var` takes effect from the beginning of the function regardless of where you write it.

Your code is **exactly** the same as this:

```
var x = 3;
(function (){
 var x;

 console.log('before', x);
 x = 7;
 console.log('after', x);
 return ;
})();
```

And of course, variables start with the value `undefined`.

Details: [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

Comment: but then if that is the case then it should show before 7...right?

Comment: @harikrish Just the declaration is moved to the top, not the assignment!

Comment: @harikrish: No, see the code I posted. As Sirko says, *only* the declaration takes effect from the top. The short version is: Upon entry to the function, before *any* step-by-step code is executed, all variables declared with `var` are instantiated (with the value `undefined`) and anywhere there's a `var x = 7;` statement, it becomes `x = 7;` (assignment rather than initialization).

Answer (score 1):

The scope of a variable is much simpler than in other languages. It doesn't start at declaration but is either :

- the function in which you have the declaration
- the global scope if the declaration isn't in a function

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) :

> The scope of a variable declared with var is the enclosing function
>   or, for variables declared outside a function, the global scope (which
>   is bound to the global object).

You can imagine that all variable declarations are moved to the start of the scope (the function). So this is exactly like

```
var x = 3;
(function (){
  var x;
  console.log('before', x); // now undefined
  x = 7;
  console.log('after', x); // now 7
  return ;
})();
```

Be careful to understand what is the exact scope (the function, not the block) :

```
var x = 3;
(function (){
  console.log('before', x); // this is undefined !
  if (true) {
      var x = 7;
  }
  return ;
})();
```